# Adjusting longnamesfirst to use et. al. on first occurence with more than 3 authors

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am making final adjustments to my thesis, ensuring that I am using the correct citation rules etc. Now it turns out I need to use all the authors' names in a citation on the first occurrence, as prescribed by APA. Afterwards et al. will suffice. I found out this can be achieved by using `longnamesfirst` as a parameter when I call natbib. However, there is an article that has 30 or so authors (yeah, I know, right?) This creates one hell of a list of authors in my text. I checked the APA rules again, and these state that if there are more than 3 authors I can use et al, even on the first occurrence. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: you might want to check out biblatex for this .... http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex

Comment: I tried that for other issues, but converting to biblatex caused a hole lot of other things to not go as I wanted. Decided to stick to  natbib.

Comment: Is this issue still unsolved for natbib? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Giuseppe, I had to actually check the document I created back then. I ended up not solving the problem and sticking to the et. al. format, even on the first mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably too late, but I reached your post and searching a bit more I think I found the answer. You can fix that by using

```
\shortcites{key-list}
```

before the first occurrence of the citation to the reference of many authors. Instead of "key-list", you should list the citation keys of all bib entries for which the first citation call-outs should use the "FirstSurname et al" format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your answer a bit to make use of the site's auto-prettyprinting of lines of code and to streamline the exposition.

Comment: Way too late indeed, but still marked it as the correct answer.